# asp .net webservice insert

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services

Hi Im trying to use webservice with ajax to get data and insert. 
To get data I use this ;

```
  [WebMethod]
    public string MenuInsert(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            using (Models.HaberScriptEntities db = new Models.HaberScriptEntities())
            {





                var res = (from i in db.MasterMenu
                           where
                               i.Id == id
                           select i.MenuName).FirstOrDefault();

                return res;

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

And I use ajax with button click to get it;
here is the script in my menuList.aspx ;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getUserName() {
        var id = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_UserId").val();
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_Result").delay(200).hide("slow");
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: "/WebService/MenuServices.asmx/GetUserName",
            data: "{id:'" + id + "'}",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.d != null) {
                    $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_Result").text(data.d);
                    $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_Result").css("color", "#FF6600");
                }
                else {
                    $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_Result").text("not found");
                    $("ContentPlaceHolder1_Result").css("color", "red");

                }
                $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_Result").delay(200).slideDown("slow");

            },
            error: function () {

            }

        });

        return false;



    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_Search").click(getUserName);
        $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_Result").css("display", "none");
    });



</script>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<div class="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="page-content">





        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <!-- BEGIN PAGE TITLE & BREADCRUMB-->
                <h3 class="page-title">
                MFT Haber Scripti V1  <small>Admin Paneli</small>
                </h3>
                <ul class="page-breadcrumb breadcrumb">
                    <li>
                        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                        <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="pull-right">

                    </li>
                    <li>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- END PAGE TITLE & BREADCRUMB-->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END PAGE HEADER-->

        <div class="clearfix">

<form runat="server">
<asp:Label ID="Result" runat="server" Text="Label" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="X-Large" ForeColor="#FF6600"></asp:Label>
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="UserId" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:Button Id="Search" runat="server" Text="Button" />
```

Now I want to add into the database via textbox.I cant get textbox Id to MenuService.asmx.cs How can i do it ? Please help

```
 protected void addmebaby_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (HaberScriptEntities db = new HaberScriptEntities())
        {
            MasterMenu create = new MasterMenu();

            create.MenuName = name.Text.Trim();


            db.MasterMenu.Add(create);
            db.SaveChanges();

         //   Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", 1 + "; #MenuDiv");   

        }

    }
```

so this add me babyclick from codebehind I want to do this in the webservice page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In var id you are gtting value of textbox not the id for textbox try this

```
var id = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_UserId").id;
```

OR

```
var id = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_UserId").attr('id');
```

Comment: Should I write this to script ? or webservice page if webservice page then it didnt work

Comment: It should be write into your script as this is jquery code to get id.
It pass to server side by this line you already write 
data: "{id:'" + id + "'}"

Comment: For the script Im getting data from webservice. I want to send data to server via web service just like button onclick from code behind

Comment: for example  protected void addmebaby_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (HaberScriptEntities db = new HaberScriptEntities())
            {
                MasterMenu create = new MasterMenu();

                create.MenuName = name.Text.Trim();


                db.MasterMenu.Add(create);
                db.SaveChanges();

             //   Response.AppendHeader("Refresh", 1 + "; #MenuDiv");   
               
            }
          
        } this is from codebehind I want to do this in webservice

Comment: your data object you build in your script contain 1 variable id but your Page asmx the web service with 2 parameters..
Is your web service call by this script..?? i don't think so..
pass value for name variable too in your data object

Comment: Oh sorry there is no string in use. I was trying something I forgot to deleteso 1 cariable Id and 1 parameter

Comment: I understand your question in case of code behind id's of textboxes available but in case of web service you should pass id using script.

Comment: So I can pass it with this ? var id = $("#ContentPlaceHolder1_UserId").attr('id');                           Gives Id to text box but I need to call it on webservice

Comment: If your string is not in use then remove it from the parameters.. your textbox is on the same asmx page where you write this web service....

Comment: then I can just use like   data: "{id:'" + id + "'}", this to get id or string from the page ?

Comment: not understand your point... You write this script to call your web service..?? When this script run id is passed to the parameter id present in your web service...
else what you want please clear the point..

Comment: Okay I have a MenuList.aspx with script , 1 label , 1 textbox , 1 button. in the script I take the Id which is entered to textbox then I use it in the asmx (webService) page I control the Id and return Name Then I get the name to the Label. Now I want to have 1 more Textbox and button take the text and enter the database just like codebehind(addmebabyclick). But I cant get the textbox text to create data. Lİttle bit confused here :D

Comment: The Point is Get text and add it to the server on webservice I can control from textbox but I need to add